# mocking getting failed in nestjs

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, nestjs

'I have below method in `nestjs`.

```
  async findAll(queryCertificateDto: QueryCertificateDto): Promise<Certificate[]> {
        const { requestStatus, startDate, endDate } = queryCertificateDto;

        const query = this.certificateRepository.createQueryBuilder('certificate');

        if (requestStatus) {
            query.andWhere('certificate.requestStatus=:requestStatus', {
                requestStatus,
            });
        }

        if (startDate && endDate) {
            query.andWhere('CAST(certificate.createdAt as Date) BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate', {
                startDate,
                endDate,
            });
        } else if (startDate) {
            query.andWhere('CAST(certificate.startDate as Date)=:startDate', { startDate });
        } else if (endDate) {
            query.andWhere('CAST(certificate.endDate as Date)=:endDate', { endDate });
        }

        const certificates = await query.getMany();
        return certificates;
    }
```

and I am writing below test case

```
 let service: CertificatesService;
    let repository: Repository<Certificate>;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
            providers: [
                CertificatesService,
                {
                    provide: getRepositoryToken(Certificate),
                    useValue: {
                        find: jest.fn().mockReturnValue([new Certificate()]),
                        findOne: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(new Certificate()),
                        save: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(new Certificate()),
                        softRemove: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(new Certificate()),
                    },
                },
            ],
        }).compile();

        service = module.get<CertificatesService>(CertificatesService);
        repository = module.get<Repository<Certificate>>(getRepositoryToken(Certificate));
    });
```

test case:-

```
it('should find all certificate', async () => {
    const queryCertificateDto = new QueryCertificateDto();
    const certificate = await service.findAll(queryCertificateDto);
    expect(repository.find).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(repository.find).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ where: queryCertificateDto });
    expect(certificate).toEqual(expect.arrayContaining([new Certificate()]));
});
```

it is getting failed with below error.

[image]

so I changed it like below.
then I added at top

```
createQueryBuilder: jest.fn().mockReturnValue([new Certificate()]),
```

and wrote below test case.

```
it('should find all certificate', async () => {
    const queryCertificateDto = new QueryCertificateDto();
    const certificate = await service.findAll(queryCertificateDto);
    expect(repository.createQueryBuilder).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(repository.createQueryBuilder).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ where: queryCertificateDto });
    expect(certificate).toEqual(expect.arrayContaining([new Certificate()]));
});
```

now it is giving error on getMany()

[image]

what additional thing I need to add in my test case?

Comment: createQueryBuilder naturally returns the queryBuilder which created the sql query for given dialect.  at least it looks like that now

Comment: I am usually writing tests with database sqlite3 in memory, so i do not have to mock anything in tests regarding actualy fetching of data.  But here i would go and mock queryBuilder to return mocked object, so i can check if mocked functions in mocked object were executed